# Floating window wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, window, floating

I want to create floating child window in my application. It should be look like floating bin in internet market. Window.ShowDialog is not well because user hasnt access to main window. Window with topmost = true as well bad idea because i want to have floating window only in limited area of main window.

Comment: [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFdockinglib.aspx) discusses the floating window and a whole docking library.